# Result of SELECT statement as Input Value PHP

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a query that echos the results of a row...

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT dba_name, contact_owner, phone, confirmation_code, physical_address, physical_city, physical_state, physical_zip, urep FROM mpas";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Later, I echo some results for the user to see...

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<strong>Confirmation Code: " . $row["confirmation_code"]. "<br></strong>";
.....
?>
```

Further in the code, I want to use the same result as a value of a hidden field. I've tried a few things with no success. The value is blank/empty. Here's my most recent attempt.

```
<?php echo "<input hidden name='confc' value='".$row['confirmation_code']."'>" ; ?>
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I am not doing, but hoping someone can help me out. I've tried looking around the web for an answer, but am having a hard time coming up with an answer that applies to this specific issue.

Comment: Are you doing it on same page ? or you are having the connection object on the page you are retrieving ?

Comment: Do you echo the hidden input inside the while or outside of it?

Comment: _Further in the code, I want to use the same result_ Do you want to use this again inside the while loop or has the while loop that is consuming all the result set finished by then

Comment: you're doing the second echo OUTSIDE the loop, which means you'll have only the last "false" value returned from the fetch call.

Comment: it's a freaking typo `<input hidden name` no "type". (for one thing)

Comment: Show us all the relevant code. Where does your form start end, where does this HIDDEN field appear in relation to your WHILE loop

Comment: Also if you have gone for a coffee and a danish **I hope you brought enough back for everybody sitting here waiting for you!!!**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wonder if I can get an espresso instead, eh Smokey? That danish though, sure sounds yummo though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you've done another query in the meantime (and even if you haven't, you're not looping anything). Try something like this:

```
<?php
$codes = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $codes[] = $row['confirmation_code'];
        echo "<strong>Confirmation Code: " . $row["confirmation_code"]. "<br></strong>";
.....
foreach ($codes as $c) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='confc' value='".$c."'>" ;
}
?>
```

Note that if you get multiple rows back, you're only going to get one `confc` value (the last one). If that's what you want, then great I guess (although you could then just use a string rather than an array). If not, you'll have to put an identifying number on the name of the hidden:

```
foreach ($codes as $k=>$c) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='confc".$k."' value='".$c."'>" ;
}
```

Comment: You also repeated OP's syntax error `<input hidden name` with no "type", equal and quotes.

Comment: I assumed that was deliberate so [s]he can see whether or not [her]his field is working without having to check the source. Either way, it makes no difference to the question (or the answer).

Comment: Yeah I know. That question's a regular can of worms. Many received downvotes because of it and I can honestly say that it wasn't me. People who give answers in trying to help out, shouldn't be punished for someone else's mistake.

Comment: I fixed it to keep everyone happy.

Comment: Right on. Well, the OP seems to have run off somewhere. We'll see what the OP has to say about all this.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in my response. I wasn't getting notified of replies and hadn't realized there was activity on here.

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the value to a php variable if you're going to use it multiple times? 
*( This **might not fix** the issue but it could iron out some possible problems )*

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $confc = $row[`confirmation_code`];
```

Then place it as the value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="confc" value="<?php echo $confc; ?>">
```

Or if you're going to continue with **echoing** it, *something like this*:

```
<?php echo "<input type= 'hidden' name='confc' value='".$confc."'>";?>
```

Comment: That isn't my downvote, but this is incorrect `<input hidden name` and have repeated the OP's syntax error. You even have the right syntax above it `<input type="hidden" name`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't notice, I copied and pasted his code thanks though

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey do you recommend any php books?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any books. I pull all my stuff from the web and from here on Stack ;-)

Comment: books are for kids :) My fingers type faster than paper cut searches in an index page, plus they lead back to better answers on @Fred-ii- posts

Answer (score 0):

You can declare another array that stores all the rows referenced by the primary key of the SELECT database table. If none of your select columns is a primary key then you have to add it in your select statement e.g. `id column`

```
$sql = "SELECT id, dba_name, contact_owner, phone, confirmation_code, physical_address, physical_city, physical_state, physical_zip, urep FROM mpas";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $all_rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $all_rows[$row["primary_key_of_your_table"]] = $row;
        echo "<strong>Confirmation Code: " . $row["confirmation_code"]. "<br></strong>";
    }
}
```

So, later you can use $all_rows to print some HTML like this:

```
if (isset($all_rows[1])) { //Access the row with primary key 1 (as an example)
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name='confc' value='".$all_rows[1]['confirmation_code']."'>" ; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not declaring hidden properly:

```
<input type="hidden" ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don`t you store that in a variable?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $confirmation_code = $row["confirmation_code"];

echo "<strong>Confirmation Code: " . $row["confirmation_code"]. "<br></strong>";
.....

<?php echo "<input hidden name='confc' value='"$confirmation_code"'>" ; ?>
```

Comment: Not my downvote here neither. But you also repeated one of the OP's syntax error `<input hidden name`. The "type" was left out.

Answer (score -2):

There's no need to echo more than you need to so.

```
<input type="hidden" name="confc" value="<?php echo $row['confirmation_code']; ?>" />
```